# jquery mobile: dynamic list not shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-lists, dynamic-html

This is my script: http://clouderize.it/demo/

First I ask how many items does it has to create: minimum 6.

After I ask the name of the item and after submitting, the relative `li` elements are added to the `ul` element.

The problem is that the html code is correctly added to the page, but it doesn't appear on the page.

my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/PeS2D/559/

What am I missing?

Comment: you can do 
$(element).listview('refresh');

Comment: are you using jquery or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you need to refresh the listview:

```
  $("#sortable").listview();
  $("#sortable").listview("refresh");
```

Try inserting both lines, for creating the listview and then to refresh it and showing the elements.

**EDIT**
The problem is with the display property of the div:

```
   $('.thirdStep').css('display', 'block');
```

instead of:

```
    $('.thirdStep').page();
    $('.thirdStep').show();
```

Comment: change property for showing the div thirdStep and it will be shown! Edit made in my answer

Comment: find $('.thirdStep').page();$('.thirdStep').show(); in your code and change it for $('.thirdStep').css('display', 'block');